# How do you open up a gallery from a button?

Tags: android, button, gallery, photo

I have a button made and when clicked I would like it to open up a gallery.  How would I do this?

Comment: You can find several answers by just searching from Stack Overflow. This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code) for example.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016352/377628) about this. You need to make an `Intent`. Here's the code from that answer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

Comment: i tried this but i didn't work

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: nothing if you can help can you go here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489781/trouble-opening-the-gallery#comment15175619_11489781