# Android open gallery app

Tags: android, button, gallery

I have a button which opens the android gallery app. I use the code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
 "content://media/internal/images/media")); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

for Android>=2.3 found here: [Open Gallery App in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416122/open-gallery-app-in-android)

My problem: When the user opens the gallery from my app and leaves gallery (home button, share image,..), then the gallery will show up next time the user opens my app (without button click).

How can I avoid the gallery is shown in my app when opening my app? The gallery should only be shown once when the button is clicked, but not next time my app gets in front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option given what your requirements appear to be is to tell Android not to save the Gallery in your task's history. That way, when they leave the Gallery activity it will not appear in the task's history stack. Do that by setting a flag on your intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media")); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```