# How to use inbuilt Equalizer by intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I am working in a media player project but for equalizer .I want to call the inbuilt equalizer  in my app but How to open an equalizer using intent ,I am able to open gallery  but How I can open an equalizer?
I am following these [Open gallery app by Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928727/open-gallery-app-from-android-intent),[Open gallery app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416122/open-gallery-app-in-android)

Comment: What inbuilt equalizer?

Comment: The one used by the default mediaplayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to open the media player equalizer by the following way

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Hope it will help some one.