# Android - Gallery App NullPointerException - OnePlus One

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm opening the Gallery app through my App using this code -

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(galleryIntent);
```

and when I select "Open with Gallery", the gallery app crashes with this stacktrace on OnePlus One device -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cyngn.gallerynext/com.cyngn.gallerynext.app.fullscreenviewer.FullscreenViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:470)
                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:460)
                                                   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:432)
                                                   at com.cyngn.gallerynext.app.fullscreenviewer.FullscreenViewer.a(SourceFile:305)
                                                   at com.cyngn.gallerynext.app.fullscreenviewer.FullscreenViewer.onCreate(SourceFile:217)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I don't want to pass a particular URI to it, I just want it to open the default gallery folder. How do I avoid this crash?

Comment: Without specific type still not working? Also try add permissions: _READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_ and _WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6016311/5156075

Comment: @JohnJoe isn't "content://media/internal/images/media" the similar to android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki oh wow thanks a lot, I already had the permissions but removing `setType()` worked! Why is that though? Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use without `setType("image/*")`

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(galleryIntent);
```

`yourIntent.setType(String mimeType)` this is represent  MIME type data that u want to get.  Using `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media` you have constant MIME. I guess,here you find more [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **only** open app(because you write: *I just want it to open the default gallery folder*):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.cyngn.gallerynext");
```

or

If you want to get any data from gallery, [see this post how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code).

Comment: Hey is this valid for all versions/phones? Will I need a build version check?

Comment: Opening specific app "com.cyngn.gallerynext" is work only on cyanogen mod. On other android builds can be app for opening photos another. Also intent will be work on any phone