# How to open gallery in specified folder using intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Can you help me how to open gallery in specified folder using intent?
It only opening gallery from specified folder like this (screenshot below).

However, it is not returning any value or activity.

I've try a lot of methods, but none open the specified gallery folder

I tried

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works, but only opening gallery, not in specified folder

another one

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/CameraExample/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

this will open recent file, but it's not just viewing gallery, it choose a file, and return it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/CameraExample/");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

and it only shows a whitescreen. Is it possible to open gallery in specified folder? It would open like this if possible:

[image: Screenshot - opening gallery in folder]

Comment: why are you creating the intent in a new task?

Comment: @Remario I just want to open gallery, and want it to seperated from my app

Comment: could you provide an example of this location or locations

Comment: it would be opened like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fSqy.jpg
it open gallery in folder screenshoot

Comment: I take it that, that screen shows all recent pictures , such recently viewed, uploaded, and received from apps like WhatsApp?

Comment: no, it's all from my default gallery, it shows where the screenshot obtained, what I want is opening galley in specific folder, like folder Pictures or etc

Comment: quick question, intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");,  do you understand what this line is saying

Comment: file type that opened.. I've changed it into "video/* image/*"

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to open gallery in specified folder?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The gallery selection was not designed to be opened from any location like that. Supported locations:

1. Album location(
   /sdcard/dcim)

Comment: also why are you just starting the activity shouldn't you be using startActivityForResult, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code

Comment: I've tried it, it's selecting an image and return value.. what I want is only showing gallery in specified folder, so it's separated from my apps.. so I think it's imposible