# How to open built-in gallery app on click button

Tags: java, android, gallery, media, photo-gallery

From my app on click the button open gallery app.
for example, MI's phone has its own gallery app, Samsung, Oneplus, etc. so how can I open the built-in gallery app?

**note**
I don't want to take images from the gallery. just only open like chrome, camera, map, etc.

Comment: Check this answer it may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code

Comment: I want to just open the app. not to get images from the gallery. like on click open chrome, map, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code to open Gallery app:
`startActivity(Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY))`

For more info related to [CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY)