# how to send photo from android device to FTP server

Tags: android, ftp-server

how to send camera capture photo from android device to FTP server

Comment: you can use simple java ftp code to do your task..what problem are you facing?

Comment: see this ans , this is best way

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172253/capture-image-show-and-send-to-server-in-android

Comment: I have added the ftp connection code but nothing is happenning.in log file nothing is showing.no errors no warnings no messages.

Comment: @Rohit-I have tried this one but nothing is happenning