# i want to add text after capture image and then want to share that image

Tags: android

i have done with image capture now i want to add some text on captured image.

Also i want to save it as image and want to share.

Following is the code.

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
private Uri mUri;
private Bitmap mPhoto;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.snap)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate)).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}




   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()== R.id.snap) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.jpg");
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
        } else {
            if (mPhoto!=null) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                mPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPhoto , 0, 0, mPhoto.getWidth(), mPhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11318277/1777090 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027720/android-how-to-save-captured-image-into-phones-gallery

Comment: i have checked that but  still i will try again..if i get successful result