# How to handle Long Press on Android Navigation Bar menu key?

Tags: android, navigationbar, long-press

I try to handle a long press event on the Navigation Bar (soft keys) to perform an action Inside my Activity. My phone is runing Android 4.4.4.

I tried to override onKeyDown() and onKeyLongPress(), but none of this Handler receive this event.

I didn't find any example of this. Is it possible to do and how ?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, since those buttons are not part of your application (the same way detecting "home" press is not possible).

Comment: Thanks ! That's frustrating. Apparently it's posible to handle de Back button : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956587/android-code-to-handle-return-button-of-the-softkey-or-return-button-which-is-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible, **since those buttons are not part of your application** (the same way detecting "home" press is not possible).

Yes, the "back" button has its API callback, `Activity.onBackPressed()` but there is not API for the other buttons, which are only handled by the system/launcher.

So I'm afraid there is no way to achieve what you asked. (Sadly if you will, but that is by design and I'm sure you can see why).

Comment: Thanks  ! I just wander on things which is related to this question. On some Android device, the physical "menu" button is used to list the runing app and sometimes open a Menu on long press on some application. I wander how it's done and if it behave the same with soft Keys ?