# Using the built-in honeycomb gallery app to display application specific images

Tags: android, gallery

I would like to use the built-in gallery application to display images stored in an application specific folder - images stored in the folder returned by the `getExternalFilesDir()` method.  There's plenty of code similar to the following that displays all images, but I need to display images stored in a specific folder:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, TEST_RESULT);
```

An answer to a similar question referenced this solution:
[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically/2636538#2636538)

However, I do not want the user to pick a photo, but rather just display them.  One answer referred to the calling `intent.setType` with `"file:///sdcard/image/*"`.

However, this did not appear to work for anyone in the responses and it did not work for me either (I tried various things like `"file://" + getExternalFilesDir() + "/*"`, etc...).  Has anyone had any luck invoking the gallery app for a specific folder?