# open image form built_in gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I have read this link :Open an image in Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically), and the code looks well.

It results with following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz3S8.png, but this is not the result I want.

I want to open the gallery similar to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoUvU.png.
I want to choose the pic form the folder gallery.

Do you know how to modify the code?

I used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.gallery", "com.android.camera.GalleryPicker"));

//   intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Log.i("aa","adafdsfa");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Through I get the folder gallery, but I cannot get the pic path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sdcard/yourfolder");
        Log.d("File path ", dir.getPath());
        String dirPath=dir.getAbsolutePath();
        if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            // tells your intent to get the contents
            // opens the URI for your image directory on your sdcard
                            //its upto you what data you want image or video.
            intent.setType("image/*");
        //  intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(dir));
        //  intent.setType("media/*");
        //  intent.
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            showToast("No file exist to show");
        }   


      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == 1) {
         if (data==null) {
            showToast("No image selected");
            //finish();
        }
         else
         {
         Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

      //  String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

         //MEDIA GALLERY
       String  selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

         if(selectedImagePath!=null)
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setData(selectedImageUri);
             startActivity(intent);
         }

         else
         {
             showToast("Image path not correct");
         }


     }
        }

}
```