# How to store the selected image from android gallery into remote database?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. My requirement is to **store image from android gallery to remote mysql database**. I am able to store the image into database by giving the **image name** in the code. But I want to store the **selected image to database from gallery** without mentioning the name of the image in the code. How can I do that?
   Please help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the gallery by [starting Activity for result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("image/*"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

Described here in more detail: [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)