# Get all images from gallery and make animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gallery, mediastore

I am new to android, please help me to resolve this. I need to retrieve all images from gallery and show that like an animation using timer or thread. I Used below code get images from gallery how can I store the images in an array?My idea is to make animation using timer by picking images from an array and put in a single Imageview. but I could not store the images retrieved from gallery to an array. I could display it in gridview by using Imageadapter. In short I need to get n number of images from gallery and place it in an array and make animation using timer and single imageview.

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
cursor=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,null,null,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AnimationDrawable and it's addFrame method. Here is the [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

Comment: I want to retrieve all the images available in the gallery

Comment: ok, i edit my answer ;) Firstly get your all images and convert them to drawable and use AnimationDrawable with calling addFrame method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below link.

It will show how you can select multiple images from gallery;

[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

[how to get all the images from in built gallery to my application...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850393/how-to-get-all-the-images-from-in-built-gallery-to-my-application)