# Statactivity from non activity

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to select the image from Gallery,but unexpectedly i face the issue as startactivity from non activity context,so i couldn't able to retrieve the path of selected image from gallery. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you pass the instance of the activity to this non-activity class as a method parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to implement the functionality you want.

Try this..

[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)