# Android intent image

Tags: android, image, android-intent

How can I open a image with another app like the gallery ?

so which intent do I have to call ?

```
Intent in=new Intent("intent?");
         startActivity(in);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open an image in Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

Comment: Check out [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically

Comment: Chekc out [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically

Comment: I want to show a picture not to select one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create an Intent for Android to show a image/png.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

Just make sure the file is in a place visible to all, not in your private sandbox.  Saving it to sdcard in the data folder is common eg. /sdcard/data/appname/filename.png

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
       intent.setData(android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.Data);
```