# upload multiple images from Gallery to server in android

Tags: android, http-post, android-camera, android-gallery, image-uploading

i m working with one application that have one functionality to upload multiple images from android inbuilt `Gallery/Camera` . i had upload single image using below [this URL](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

. my exact requirement is that when i click on `Button` (upload from gallery) than inbuilt Gallery will be open . i am able to select single/multiple images from this Gallery and upload selected images to my `Server` . Any one have idea please help me how can i make this possible ?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post on stackoverflow. 
Given that you want to use the inbuilt gallery this post answers your question.

[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

If you choose not to use the inbuilt gallery then I recommend reading this
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Both solutions shall work but which one you want to use will be dictated by your application requirements.

Comment: Thanx alot .. your link is help to opne inbuGallery from button click event. But my main concern is that How to upload select and upload multiple images which we had select from inbuilt Gallery ?

Comment: As far as I know you can only do single select on the gallery (but I may be wrong since I have not used gallery in such a way so please double check this in Android Documentation). I would suggest going through the example in the second link in my answer. When you select an image simply add the image name to a vector and then in your async task simply go through all the entries in the vector, assuming here that your async task has the Url to which you want to upload.

Comment: This is half the answer. Any chance you have an example of uploading multiple images to a server (at once, not just uploading a single image multiple time sequentially).