# Get the gallery in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I want to get the android gallery view into my application with showing all the photos in the thumbnail mode. How can i do this?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Don't just thank Rajesh, accept the answer. That's how this works.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196411/1705590) is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the similar questions.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616419/how-can-i-get-android-inbuilt-image-gallery-in-to-my-application)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876996/showing-images-of-gallery-in-my-application)

and also this

```
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                    // select a file
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
}
```

From [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636538/1412308)

Hope this may helpful