# image from gallery to image in bytes.. also data in bytes.. for facebook upload in android

Tags: android

I got code to upload picture and video to Face Book..
But i don't know how to convert image from gallery to image in bytes.. also data in bytes.. Any one can help me????

```
*Upload picture,
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 params.putByteArray("picture", <image in bytes>);
 params.putString("message", "Have fun");
 mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());* 

this is code for upload images...   
*Upload video,
Bundle params = new Bundle();
param.putString("filename", <dataName>);
param.putByteArray("video", <data in bytes>);
 mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());**

this is code for upload images...    
Any one know how code for my question please post.....
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get file path from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

Try it -

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int data;

while((data != is.read()) != -1)
   bs.write(data);

is.close();
byte[] raw = bs.toByteArray();
bs.close();
```

Comment: FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int data;

while((data != is.read()) != -1)
   bs.write(data);

is.close();
byte[] raw = bs.toByteArray();
bs.close();

Comment: data is not initalized do i have to initiate to 0

Answer (score 0):

This is one way how you convert a bitmap to byte:

```
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos); 
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```