# Open an image with Android Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I need to open a specific image in Android Gallery, but I tried some codes with no success.
This is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse( "file:///Download/screenshot.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It seems the Android Gallery is open but with no image, it show a black screen.

I'm trying my app in a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with ICS 4.0

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks,
Víctor.

Comment: How does the file get there? it could be a permission problem, when the file is written it depends wether the MODE_WORLD_READABLE flag was set during writing.

Comment: There is a complete answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) page.

Comment: Is the file path correct? Shouldn't there be sdcard in there somewhere?

Comment: Uri.parse( "file://sdcard/Download/screenshot.jpg") ??

Comment: First at all, thank you every one you have answer my question. And special thanks to SmartLemon, because I only added "scard" to my path file and... It worked!