# How to determine when an image in a gallery in an Android app is long pressed?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I'm writing an image application and I need to determine when an image is long pressed and do some processing on the image? I'm not sure how to listen to a long press for an image in the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a view such as ImageView, you can use [setOnLongClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29) and pass it an [OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) to process your image.

Comment: I'm new to android development so what I'm not understanind is that the view is not mine. It's android. So when a user clicks the gallery it's a view that is not part of my application. How do I hook into the gallery?

Comment: To clarify the point a little more I"m not interested in showing the images in my own view. When the user clicks an image in the gallery I want to process the image. Maybe keep track of which images was clicked and display a report for example.

Comment: Do a little more research I don't think this is possible since it's a different view.

Comment: Then you need to post some code and adjust your question because I don't fully understand it. The way I described above is a way to handle an image being long pressed which is what your original question asked.

Comment: This will load the images into my activity.

Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

Comment: Clarification: when I said "Do a little more research..." I was referring to my self. I meant to say I did a little more research.

Comment: Haha, yeah I was a bit confused by your "do a little more research.." comment. And could you post more of your code in your answer? You might want to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) to see if this is what you're trying to do. If so, I'll add that to my answer above.