# Cannot use PhotoSwipe with android webview

Tags: android, webview, gallery, photoswipe

This is my web view configuration

```
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();                           
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    myWebView.clearHistory();
    myWebView.clearFormData();
    myWebView.clearCache(true);


    //Set URL
    setExplorer(url+lang);

    //Set Click Url
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }


    });



    //Set Progress Bar
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
        {
            if(progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

            }
            Pbar.setProgress(progress);
            if(progress == 100) {
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

The url I am trying is "http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html"

when my webview load webpages everything looks fine, but when I click an image from image gallery, I see a long height scrollbar, I won´t see the image, or at least not correctly like If I were using google chrome from android 4.2.1.

I doesn´t work for me, I´m using android api 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

Comment: Nope, the problem is with fitting the image or de show