# Accessing image in gallery to create SqlLite database table in android

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development.  I'm creating an app for augmented reality. My objective is to capture a video of real environment and to display an augmented image of the past related to the real environment.
Can you please guide me how to create a new SqlLite database table for accessing images(augmented images) which is already saved in the gallery of Nexus tab 7? Also I'm taking the GPS co-ordinates for reference to create a virtual table.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create you database with the BLOB datatype for storing the image.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) is another question that addresses retrieving the images from the photo gallery.  Good luck.