# Adding a picture from gallery

Tags: android

In regards to this post [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

What is `R.layout.main` and `((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))` supposed to be?

Because shouldnt the content view be the phones gallery? In whcih case it should already be there. And what is the button?

EDIT: I am getting the image in the form of a string that says `external/images/media/12`. How can I set the image of an `ImageView` using this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Intent Action, `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` android automatically takes the user to new system activity to choose a file. so not related to button and layout that this code have.

Answer (score 1):

you should add "main.xml" to res/layout (if not exist!)
and append this code to it :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >    

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
ImageView image = null;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("Your image browse");      
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```