# Android - How to take a picture from camera or gallery

Tags: android, image, camera

I would like to ask the user to take a picture, either from camera or from the existing pictures in the device (gallery or whatever). How can I do that?

I have implemented the solution below, which seems to work fine, but the documentation is quite confusing so I would like to know if there are better solutions.

Also, check out this related post. There you will see how to get the image path or Bitmap: [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

So, in my solution you would create a `TakePictureHelper` object and do the following.

Let's say you display a dialog where the user can choose "camera" or "other". When the user chooses an option you would call either `takeFromCamera()` or `takeFromOther()`. When the picture is taken (or not) the `onActivityResult()` method will be called. There you would call `retrievePicture`, which will return the Uri of the picture or null if no picture was taken.

Please let me know what you think, share ideas or ask me anything if I wasn't clear.

Thank you very much!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TakePictureHelper {

    public final static int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    public final static int REQUEST_OTHER = 2;

    private Uri cameraImageUri;

    /**
     * Request picture from camera using the given title
     */
    public void takeFromCamera(Activity activity, String title)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File cameraImageOutputFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                createCameraImageFileName());
        cameraImageUri = Uri.fromFile(cameraImageOutputFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImageUri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, title), REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    /**
     * Request picture from any app (gallery or whatever) using the given title
     */
    public void takeFromOther(Activity activity, String title)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, title), REQUEST_OTHER);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the picture, taken from camera or gallery.
     *
     * @return the picture Uri, or null if no picture was taken.
     */
    public Uri retrievePicture(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Uri result = null;

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_OTHER) {
                result = data.getData();
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                result = cameraImageUri;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private String createCameraImageFileName() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return timeStamp + ".jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

based on @yurezcv's answer, here's what I came up with (Most importantly how to retrieve image in onActivityResult):

```
private List<File> cameraImageFiles;

private void popImageChooser(){
    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);

    cameraImageFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    int i=0;
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME, ".nomedia");

        File cameraImageOutputFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                createCameraImageFileName());
        cameraImageFiles.add(cameraImageOutputFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i)));
        i++;

        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.attach_images_title));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
           Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri uri = null;
            if(imageReturnedIntent == null){   //since we used EXTRA_OUTPUT for camera, so it will be null

                for(int i=0;i<cameraImageFiles.size();i++){
                    if(cameraImageFiles.get(i).exists()){
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Log.d("attachimage", "from camera: "+uri);
            }
            else {  // from gallery
                uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Log.d("attachimage", "from gallery: "+uri.toString());
            }

            if(uri != null){
                attachImage(uri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `createCameraImageFileName()`, and what does it do?

Comment: @AnasAzeem it just generates a String name for the new image file taken from camera. You can write it whatever the way you like

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for me:

```
private void addPhoto() {   
       // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);     
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME, ".nomedia");

        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.add_new));

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

It creates one intent dialog with all possible variants for select image from camera, filesystem, etc.

Comment: Thank you. How do you get the image file in `onActivityResult`? Do you do the same if it comes from the camera or other app?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create in your layout a button (by clicking on this button will open a dialog where you can choose whether to choose the camera or galleria).
2. Now initializes the button in its class:

   **- Before onCreate:**

   `Button btu;`

   **- Inside onCreate:**

   `btu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtUp);`
3. Methods call camera and gallery

**- Before onCreate boot**

```
int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
```

**- Method Call camera**

```
public void callCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

**- Method Call gallery**

```
public void callGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                               MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}
```

4. Create a method to show the AlertDialog, which appear to choose:

   ```
   public void showAlertDialog(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
   final String items[] = {getString(R.string.TextTakeCam), getString(R.string.TextTakeGal)};

   AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.TextTitleDia));
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
           if (choice == 0) {
               callCamera();
           } else if (choice == 1) {
               image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               callGallery();
           }
       }});
   ab.show();
   ```

   }
5. Call AlertDialog in button

   ```
   btu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       String title = getString(R.string.TextUp);
       String msg = getString(R.string.TextUp2);
       showAlertDialog2(MainActivity.this,title,msg,true);
       //maneger.UpdateC(edname.getText().toString(),edfoto.getText().toString(),ednum. getText().toString());
       }
   });
   ```

Inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better and easy way to take picture from camera or gallery i.e. using this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3623

**You can follow the link above or follow these steps:**

Steps to use this library in your project are:

1. Add dependency to Gradle:

   compile 'com.frosquivel:magicalcamera:4.4'
2. Implementation Code:

   PermissionGranted permissionGranted = new PermissionGranted(this);
   MagicalCamera magicalCamera = new MagicalCamera(this, permissionGranted);
   //The parameter this, is the current activity
       //permission for take photo, it is false if the user check deny
       permissionGranted.checkCameraPermission();
       //for search and write photoss in device internal memory
       //normal or SD memory
       permissionGranted.checkReadExternalPermission();
       permissionGranted.checkWriteExternalPermission();
3. Call to Take Photo From Camera:

   magicalCamera.takePhoto();
4. Call to Select Photo From Gallery:

   magicalCamera.selectedPicture("my_header_name");
5. Override OnActivityResult(); method to get Bitmap and Path:

   ```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   magicalCamera.resultPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data);//with this form you obtain the bitmap
   Bitmap bitmap = magicalCamera.getPhoto();
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   //if you need path of bitmap use this code
   String path = magicalCamera.savePhotoInMemoryDevice(magicalCamera.getPhoto(),"myPhotoName","myDirectoryName", MagicalCamera.JPEG, true);
   ```

   if(path != null){
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The photo is save in device, please check this path: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else{
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry your photo dont write in devide, please contact with fabian7593@gmail and say this error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }

**For more details refer to the link above**