# [Android - Kitkat ]Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically

Tags: android, android-gallery

Try to pick only one particular image from the SD card.I am able to pick images from gallery and Photos app in kikat.But not getting file path when i pick image from recents am getting file path as null.

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636538/1140321.

Comment: Do you really need the imagepath? Are you uploading the image? or just want to show it in imageview?

Comment: i just want to show it in a image view..

Comment: Can you post your code as it would be easier for me to answer

Comment: the same code i'm using as mentioned in the link.some guy even posted it as answer even.

Comment: @SunilMishra, How to store image path in sqlite database using the second method, parcelfiledescriptor (API >=19). I can store image path with method you have written for API <19 but i am not able to get the path from the second method. Please help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This works for **Kitkat**

```
public class BrowsePictureActivity extends Activity{

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String selectedImagePath;
private ImageView imageView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browsepicture);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                }
            });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            else {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                try {
                    parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImageUri, "r");
                    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
 */
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        if( uri == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return uri.getPath();
}

}
```

You need to add permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: The code is not same...check for the if else condition which checks for kitkat :P

Comment: This works for me but it's extremely slow compared to what I use for getting images in all previous API levels. Do you know why it's so slow? Talking about 5 seconds until I can actually use the image.

Comment: I'm with the same problem but the code is not working for the Kitkat :-(

Comment: HI @SunilMishra, can this be used to select an image in the gallery and insert in a sqlite database? Thanks

Comment: @MiguelRivera Yes you can store the bitmap into database, instead of setting it into imageview

Comment: @SunilMishra, How to store image path in sqlite database using the second method, parcelfiledescriptor (API >=19). I can store image path with method you have written for API <19 but i am not able to get the path from the second method. Please help.