# Android Image file path from URI

Tags: android

My Manifest activity code

```
        <activity android:name="FileReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My Activity code :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    String action = i.getAction();


if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) i.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            Log.i("1234567", "URI : " + imageUri);
            Log.i("123456", "path :" + imageUri.getPath());
            File source = null;
            source = new File(imageUri.getPath());
            String fileNme = "/" + source.getName();

            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path);
            Log.i("123456", "destination path :" + destination);
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("123456", "IO Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

im getting exception

```
01-09 16:10:09.756: W/System.err(30225): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'content:/media/external/images/media/127' does not exist
```

how do i get the path of the image when i receive an image from DCIM folder ?

Comment: Have add read- write permission in your manifest file??

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
 */
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // just some safety built in 
        if( uri == null ) {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }
        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();
}
```

source:
[Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Solved it using the following code:

```
public static String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT &&
            DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, contentUri)) {
        return getPathForV19AndUp(context, contentUri);
    } else {
        return getPathForPreV19(context, contentUri);
    }
}

private static String getPathForPreV19(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        try {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static String getPathForV19AndUp(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String documentId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
    String id = documentId.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```