# android uri.getPath() and performance

Tags: android

I am thinking about using uri.getPath().
But I am a bit confused because of a code snippet that I have seen online, shown below. In the example the author tries to retrieve the image in a different way first.

So I am wondering whether there are some serious performance disadvantages using uri.getPath()? (Or why does he not simply skip the media store part?)

```
/**
 * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
 */
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        // just some safety built in 
        if( uri == null ) {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }
        // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
        // this will only work for images selected from gallery
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();
}
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018617/3991799

Comment: I would just delete all of it.  managedQuery has been deprecated.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)

Comment: well, I am not really interested in this code snippet. I just want to know whether I can use uri.getPath() without a considerable loss of performance.

Comment: Pretty sure their is no real loss of performance. If you're really concerned, I'd just do a loop around this and have it call it > 1000000 times and just have a trace going to see how much more time it'd take.  I'd actually expect getPath() to be more performant, but nothing worth worrying about.

Comment: good guess that I need 1 million trials to get a significant difference at all. the difference is about 10 seconds (devided by the number of trials), so no reason to worry at all.