# get Path name from Uri Android Lollipop

Tags: android, uri, filepath

Lollipop version.

I used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965524/2655596) to determine file path from Uri. Works fine, but if I choose file from a Downloaded app - **getRealPathFromURI_API19** function does not work for me. whole Id for this case equals /document/4 for example, and my app was crashed.

Ok, I made some changes for this function and "id" for Uri "/document/4" now equals 4, but function returns null.

Is it possible get file path for choosed image from any app?
I need file path for ExifInterface.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835665/878126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Works fine

Only for the few devices that you tried, for the one file source (`MediaStore`) that you tried.

> Is it possible get file path for choosed image from any app?

No. [A `Uri` is not a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). There is no requirement for any `Uri` to be convertible into file path, as the `Uri` may not represent a file, let alone a file that your app has the rights to access. To you, a `Uri` is an opaque address to content owned by another app, much as a URL is an opaque address to content owned by a Web server. And, just as you cannot magically convert a URL into a file path that you can use, you cannot magically convert a `Uri` into a file path that you can use.

> I need file path for ExifInterface.

In reality, you need to read, or possibly write, EXIF headers associated with a `Uri` that you believe points to an image that contains those headers. While `ExifInterface` lets you do that, it is designed for apps to work with their own images, not images from third-party apps.

Your choices are:

- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` on the `Uri`, and make a local copy of the image, after which you can use `ExifInterface`
- Use some other EXIF code that offers more flexibility. For example, [the EXIF classes from the AOSP Mms app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/exif/ExifReader.java) can read EXIF headers from an `InputStream`