# How to open a GmsDocumentScanningResult.Pdf

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-fileprovider, google-mlkit

I would like to open a `GmsDocumentScanningResult.Pdf` object with my default PDF app.

I've tried the following:

```kotlin
resultIntent?.pdf?.let { pdf: GmsDocumentScanningResult.Pdf ->
    val pdfUri = pdf.uri
    val file = pdfUri.toFile()
    if (file.exists()) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(file.toUri(), "application/pdf")
        try {
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: FileUriExposedException) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

But it throw a FileUriExposedException with the message: `file:///data/user/0/com.mypackage.docscanner/cache/mlkit_docscan_ui_client/9724995915195.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

I think I need to use a the `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109267/android-how-to-write-camera-intent-in-android-nougat/52695444#52695444), but I'm not sure how to implement here.

I've also tried this:

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

`provider_paths.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

```kotlin
val pdfFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseContext, applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", resultIntent?.pdf?.uri?.toFile() ?: File("")).toFile()

    if (pdfFile.exists()) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(pdfFile.toUri(), "application/pdf")
        try {
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // 
        }
    }
}
```

But it's also crashing, this time with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=95110657, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.hikarisource.docscanner/com.hikarisource.docscanner.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.hikarisource.docscanner/cache/mlkit_docscan_ui_client/1376275955600.pdf
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5323)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5362)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.hikarisource.docscanner/cache/mlkit_docscan_ui_client/1376275955600.pdf
at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:849)
at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:452)
at com.hikarisource.docscanner.MainActivity.registerScanner$lambda$2(MainActivity.kt:57)
at com.hikarisource.docscanner.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$7_JDnBxGZf3SKr0da9a7J8NBWkY(Unknown Source:0)
at com.hikarisource.docscanner.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:414)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:371)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:845)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8628)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5316)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5362) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little diference on how to set the intent:

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

`provider_paths.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

    <cache-path
        name="mlkit_docscan_ui_client"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

```kotlin
resultIntent?.pdf?.let { pdf: GmsDocumentScanningResult.Pdf ->
    val pdfUri = it.uri
    val pdfFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, activity.packageName + ".provider", pdfUri.toFile())
    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, pdfFileUri)
    browserIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    activity.startActivity(browserIntent)
}
```