# Select multiple photos from android native gallery

Tags: android

I have searched many post and have yet to come across an answer that does not lead to using a 3rd party picture choosing gallery. A couple of things: I am testing with my phone that has android 4.3

I have a button on my activity that starts the intent that looks like this:

```
public void GoToPics(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( );
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "select multiple images"), SELECT_PHOTOS_RESULT);

}
```

From other posts people suggesting putting this in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="package.name.Photos"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photos" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

With the code now I get to the gallery and only get to choose a single photo. There has got to be a simple way to get multiple that im missing?

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically

Comment: I believe this will work only if those apps (including Gallery) are implemented to handle `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` intent and return you a list of images. But if they didn't implement this feature in their apps, there's no way to allow you to select multiple images.

Comment: This does make sense but I know for a fact that you can select multiple images with the default gallery I am testing with. When attaching pictures to a text message it brings up the gallery with multiple selection enabled