# Android Studio - ImageView with CameraRoll or Camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just started with Android Studio and I'm sure this question was maybe asked but:

- I have a small app with an ImageView in the center.

Below, I have 2 buttons. All I want is this:

- When one button is touched, I want the camera roll to appear, so when a photo is selected, the photo is placed inside the ImageView.
- When the other button is touched, I want the user to take a photo and the photo needs to appear in the imageView.

Is there a tutorial on this specific issue?

Mirza

Comment: it have been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically just search a bit

Comment: many thanks will check out