# How to select a file from the gallery?

Tags: android, image, file, select, android-gallery

I want to select a picture/movie file via Android gallery. I followed a similar question in SO: [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) and this solves the problem somehow.

The question is, in this code, the returned object is of `Bitmap` type. How can we return a `raw` file? I mean, I don't want it to be decoded to `Bitmap`, I just want to receive the file itself, ***as is***.

The following code is part of the solution to this question: [Get/pick an image from Android's built-in Gallery app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/get-pick-an-image-from-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
final String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();    

Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
/* Now you have choosen image in Bitmap format in object "yourSelectedImage". You can use it in way you want! */
```

So, how can I do that?

Comment: You already have the `filepath`, use that to get the `File`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is,

```
File myRawFile = new File(filePath);
```

and then use the file to get what you want. You can read more about File class from here,

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html